# Переход по ссылке на существующую вкладку, вместо открытия новой

Tags: javascript, button, браузер, link, href

Допустим, есть приложение, в нём кнопка.

```
b.setAttribute('href','https://yandex.ru')
```

При клике - перекинет на браузер, и в нём откроется новая вкладка Яндекса. Но возможно ли сделать так, что бы при клике открывалась не новая вкладка, а перекидывало на ту, что уже открыта, если конечно открыта. То есть, у человека 10 вкладок, сейчас он смотрит десятую, третья из них - Яндекс. И что бы при клике просто открывалась третья, а не создавалась одиннадцатая. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил)

Не уверен, что это вообще возможно, просто, есть четкое ощущение, что я видел это, с точки зрения пользователя. Но если вдруг возможно - поделитесь пожалуйста, как.

Вопрос про несколько строк кода, а не соображения чего то глобального.

Comment: Если сделаете приложение (расширение) к браузеру, то получите доступ ко вкладкам

Comment: У меня точно такой же вопрос!!! Пока ответ на него не нашла.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать атрибут `target='yandex.ru'`, но не факт, что будет работать корректно с такими ссылками, со своей страницей может. А вообще так делать нельзя, нет таких возможностей

Comment: К сожалению, в моём случае - не работает. А можно ли что нибудь придумать с закрепленной вкладкой, то есть, что бы по клику открывалась закрепленная вкладка, или же вкладка под определенным номером?

Comment: Думаю, в целях безопасности запрещено и так делать